# Find point on curve that has integer coordinates

Tags: geometry

Given the curve $y=256/x$ find the integer coordinates at which it intersects.

Comment: Take $x$ as any integer that divides $256$...unless I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

Try $\pm 2^k$ for $0 \leq k \leq 8$.

[image]

(Thanks to Jean Marie for reminding us that negative values might be acceptable too.)

Comment: ... and maybe as well the points obtained by symmetry from these one with respect to the origin (in fact, depending on the areas of the globe, "integers" mean $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: True enough... perhaps negative integers are allowed.  (Unclear.)